# Using split function in javascript want to split the url at the time of page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

I have a URL like below

```
    http://domain_name/?act=SiteVisit
```

I want to split this URL and want to take act value in one variable at the time of page load.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var mail_link  = window.location;   
    var arrURL     = mail_link.split('='); 
    alert(arrURL[1]);
    return false;
});
```

I used the above code but its not working.But if I print and assign the variable which i get in alert message its working

So tell me how to get the SiteVisit in a variable

Comment: Remove the quotes around `document` and see if that helps.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: why not using query? (http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `location.search`, which represents the query part of the location (everything after `?`):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    alert(location.search.split('=')[1]); 
});
```

If the string consists of more than one parameter (e.g. `?act=SiteVisit&last=yesterday`), you can decompose it with something like:

```
var params = {}, srch = location.search.split('&');
for (var i=0;i<srch.length;i+=1){
  var pair = srch[i].split('=');
  params[pair[0]]  = pair[1];
}
// for ?act=SiteVisit&last=yesterday =>
// params.act = 'SiteVisit'
// params.last = 'yesterday'
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` doesn't return anything. It should be `window.location.href`

```
var mail_link  = window.location.href;   
var arrURL = mail_link.split('='); 
alert(arrURL[1]);
return false;
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/khwjX/)

Comment: `window.location` doesn't return a string for me. Try `window.location.href`.